# Cypher procedure call with optional result

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I have a procedure that looks for the last active session for a specific user.
The procedure will return a single result or nothing.
When I execute the following cypher query, it only returns a result when both the user and the session are present.

```
MATCH (user:User) 

 CALL org.custom.last_active_session(user) YIELD session

RETURN user, session
```

How can I return the user node, even if the last_active_session procedure yields no result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is tricky. You can add a null (dummy) session by using UNION then return it with user. Then remove duplicates by doing a collect.  Lastly, get the session which is the only item in the list.

```
MATCH (user: User) 
//call your user defined function and combine (union) it with a dummy session
CALL   { WITH user
     CALL org.custom.last_active_session(user) 
        YIELD  session 
        RETURN session 
     UNION
        RETURN null as session}
//remove duplicates caused by dummy (null) session using collect
WITH user, collect(session)[0] as session
//collect returns a list and session is always a single result so it is indexed 0 
RETURN user, session
```

Sample output:

```
user   |   session |
--------------------
{id:1}    session1
{id:2}    null
```

IMO, you should handle it in your procedure.

Comment: I love this as a workaround, but hate that it's so verbose to do a simple thing. Although I think that streaming nothing is correcter than streaming an empty result, I prefer that over the verbosity of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it has to do with your custom procedure that it can't return a null value?
Anyhow, I would try to use subqueries:

```
MATCH (user:User)
CALL {WITH user
      CALL org.custom.last_active_session(user) YIELD session
      RETURN session}
RETURN user, session
```

Comment: Indeed, the situation would be different when my procedure would return a response with empty session. Your suggestion does not change anything about my original problem

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options for customizing functionality in Neo4j. The two related to your use case are `User-Defined Procedures` and `User-Defined Functions`.

Currently, you have created a `User-Defined Procedure` I think, which is expected to return a `Stream` of results and hence we use `YIELD` in Cypher.

As mentioned in the question, since your procedure returns a single value or nothing, you can create a `User-Defined Function`, which is expected to return a single value.

Once you do that, your query becomes:

```
MATCH (user:User) 
RETURN user, org.custom.last_active_session(user) AS session
```

Read more about user-defined functions [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/extending-neo4j/functions/).

Comment: A valid alternative to consider, but it doesn't answer my original question

Comment: Yes, it's an alternative only. As you have seen in the other answer, the query gets a bit verbose and unnecessarily complicated, for this simple task, Using functions, the query is cleaner, and it will return users whether their last active session is present or not.